# How can I parse a file for match, and print the string prior to matched string in Perl?

Tags: perl, parsing, fasta

I'm trying to parse a GBK file. Basically, I need to return the locus tag and product name of genes that match the pattern. So if the motif I want to search for all predicted gene product, the search word "predicted" would return:

```
/product="predicted semialdehyde dehydrogenase"
/locus_tag="ECDH10B_2481"
```

I've been able to return the `/product` but I can't figure out how to parse "backwards" to grab the `/locus_tag`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
my $fasta_file = 'example.txt';
open(INPUT, $fasta_file) || die "ERROR: can't read input FASTA file: $!";
while ( <INPUT> ) {
     if(/predicted/){
            print $_;
     }
}
```

> example.txt

```
gene            complement(2525423..2526436)
                 /gene="usg"
                 /locus_tag="ECDH10B_2481"
 CDS             complement(2525423..2526436)
                 /gene="usg"
                 /locus_tag="ECDH10B_2481"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="predicted semialdehyde dehydrogenase"
                 /protein_id="ACB03477.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:169889770"
                 /db_xref="ASAP:AEC-0002184"
                 /translation="MSEGWNIAVLGATGAVGEALLETLAERQFPVGEIYALARNESAG
                 EQL"
 gene            complement(2526502..2527638)
                 /gene="pdxB"
                 /locus_tag="ECDH10B_2482"
 CDS             complement(2526502..2527638)
                 /gene="pdxB"
                 /locus_tag="ECDH10B_2482"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="erythronate-4-phosphate dehydrogenase"
                 /protein_id="ACB03478.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:169889771"
                 /db_xref="ASAP:AEC-0002185"
                 /translation="MKILVDENMPYARDLFSRLGEVTAVPGRPIPVAQLADADALMVR
                 SVTKVNESLLAGKPIKFVGTATAGTDHVDEAWLKQAGIGFSAAP"
```

Comment: Is the extra space in front of "gene" and "CDS" a typo?

Comment: That doesn't look like FASTA format, what format is that?  There's probably an existing parser you can use.

Comment: Sorry, it's GBK format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember the last locus tag encountered and print it if predicted:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $fasta_file = 'example.txt';
open my $INPUT, '<', $fasta_file or die "ERROR: can't read input FASTA file: $!";

my $locus_tag;
while (<$INPUT>) {
    if (/locus_tag/) {
        $locus_tag = $_;
    } elsif (/predicted/) {
        print;
        print $locus_tag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't "parse backwards". Your `/locus` tag is an *event*, matching is another. Your logic should run that

1. You capture each and every locus tag and store them
2. When you match, store the locus tag in the keeper list
3. The last locus tag will automatically be clobbered when you store the next.

Comment: I thought about this too. If the file contains hundreds of thousands of entries, and you store every single tag, I thought this would significantly hinder the performance of the script. I'll try it out and see.

Comment: @user1854603, you store each one in something like `$current_locus_tag`. It's a scalar, so it only takes one value. Then when you match, you can either store it or print it. If you store it, you can change what you do with it later.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to parse backwards.  You'd be better served by parsing each complete entry and then determining if it matches.  This is a bit more work now, but it will prove very useful when you want to do something else with the gene data.

The approach I use below builds up the entry in `%entry`.  When it sees the next "gene" line it processes that entry, in this case checking for a product match, and clears it for the next one.

I've used the `DATA` file handle for testing purposes, it reads in everything after the `__DATA__` line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %entry;
while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    # new entry, process the previous one and clear it
    if( $line =~ m{^ gene \s+ complement \( (.*) \) }x ) {
        process_entry(\%entry) if keys %entry;
        %entry = ( complement => $1 );
    }
    elsif( $line =~ m{^CDS \s+ }x ) {
        # ignore CDS lines for now
    }
    elsif( $line =~ m{^\s+/(\w+)=(.*)} ) {
        $entry{$1} = $2;
    }
    else {
        warn "Unknown line $line";
    }
}

# Process the last one.
process_entry(\%entry) if keys %entry;

sub process_entry {
    my $entry = shift;

    say "MATCH! $entry->{locus_tag}" if $entry->{product} =~ /predicted/;

    return;
}


__DATA__
gene            complement(2525423..2526436)
                /gene="usg"
                /locus_tag="ECDH10B_2481"
CDS             complement(2525423..2526436)
                /gene="usg"
                /locus_tag="ECDH10B_2481"
                /codon_start=1
                /transl_table=11
                /product="predicted semialdehyde dehydrogenase"
                /protein_id="ACB03477.1"
                /db_xref="GI:169889770"
                /db_xref="ASAP:AEC-0002184"
                /translation="MSEGWNIAVLGATGAVGEALLETLAERQFPVGEIYALARNESAGEQL"
gene            complement(2526502..2527638)
                /gene="pdxB"
                /locus_tag="ECDH10B_2482"
CDS             complement(2526502..2527638)
                /gene="pdxB"
                /locus_tag="ECDH10B_2482"
                /codon_start=1
                /transl_table=11
                /product="erythronate-4-phosphate dehydrogenase"
                /protein_id="ACB03478.1"
                /db_xref="GI:169889771"
                /db_xref="ASAP:AEC-0002185"
                /translation="MKILVDENMPYARDLFSRLGEVTAVPGRPIPVAQLADADALMVRSVTKVNESLLAGKPIKFVGTATAGTDHVDEAWLKQAGIGFSAAP"
```

Alternatively there are several [Fasta readers on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=fasta) including [Bio::SeqReader::Fasta](https://metacpan.org/module/Bio%3a%3aSeqReader%3a%3aFasta) and [Bio::DB::Fasta](https://metacpan.org/module/Bio%3a%3aDB%3a%3aFasta).